# Series about three children with powers, one telepathic; unfinished when I was in school

Tags: story-identification

So when I was in grade school, I started reading a series of books that I remember really enjoying, There's little I remember other than:

It was about, I believe, three kids who had powers. One of those powers was telepathy and the author used asterisks instead of quotations to show telepathic conversations.

The reason I never finished the series was because the last book hadn't come out yet. This had to have been sometime probably in the late 90's.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69463/teenagers-taken-from-their-worlds-attracted-to-colored-gems-which-give-them-spe (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like it might be the [Diadem series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diadem_(series)) by John Peel. The first book in the series, *Book of Names*, was published in 1997.

The series is about three teenagers who have powerful magical abilities, but are initially unaware of them because they grew up on worlds where magic is very weak. They eventually start to collect gemstones which amplify specific powers; one gem in particular, agate, enables telepathic communication (denoted by asterisks).